# Action get dispatched but nothing happen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga

I'm trying get data from action payload to use in redux-saga but it return `undefined`

Here is some code

**Action**

```
export const GetUserInfo = (user, password) => {
    return{
        type: actionList.GET_USER_INFO,
        data: {user, password},
    }
};
```

**Saga part**

**LoginSaga**

```
function* loginSaga(action) {

    console.log('Saga is working')
    const getJson = yield call(requestGetUser)
    const getJsonData = getJson

    const getJsonUsername = String(getJsonData.username)
    console.log(getJson)
    console.log('getjson data ', getJsonUsername)
    console.log(action.data.username) // try to get data but return undefined

    const getJsonPassword = String(getJsonData.password)

    if (String(action.data.username) === getJsonUsername) {
        if (String(action.data.password) === getJsonPassword) {
            console.log('saga login success')
            yield put({type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS'})
            SaveToAsyncStorage(action.data)
        }
        else {
            console.log('saga password fail')
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log("saga user fail")
    }
}
export {loginSaga}
```

**WatchSaga**

```
export function* watchSaga() {
    yield takeLatest(GET_USER_INFO,loginSaga);
}
```

Main file use `useDispatch(username,password)` to store these data, it show in redux extension, but return undefined
Here is a gif to show what going on

Thank a lot

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the code for the dispatch of the method ?

Comment: of course, here is my repo, the code in the `src/Screen/Login/Login.js`
https://github.com/khanh21011999/Trainning-react-native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have close look at the repo provided by you there is a mistake you must have to do some changes as below;

replace the below code:

```
export const GetUserInfo = (user, password) => {
    return{
        type: actionList.GET_USER_INFO,
        data: {user, password},
    }
};
```

**WITH THE BELOW CODE**

```
export const GetUserInfo = (username, password) => {
    return{
        type: actionList.GET_USER_INFO,
        data: {username, password},
    }
};
```

Reason is you are trying to get the username property from the action but the return property is user.

Comment: OMG it work !!!!! i'm really grateful to you, what a silly mistake, i searched the code line by line, asked dozens of questions on stackoverflow but couldn't find a solution, THANK YOU SO SO MUCH sir, have a nice day